# Python Boolean as argument in a function

Tags: python

I have a function that needs input as True/False that will be fed in from another function. I would like to know what is the best practice to do this. Here is the example I am trying:

```
def feedBool(self, x):

    x = a_function_assigns_values_of_x(x = x)
    if x=="val1" or x == "val2" :
      inp = True
    else
      inp = False

    feedingBool(self, inp)
    return

def feedingBool(self, inp) :
    if inp :
      do_something
    else :
      dont_do_something
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def feedBool(self, x):
    x = a_function_assigns_values_of_x(x = x)    
    feedingBool(self, bool(x=="val1" or x == "val2"))
```

Or, as pointed out in the comments:

```
def feedBool(self, x):
    x = a_function_assigns_values_of_x(x = x)    
    feedingBool(self, x in ("val1","val2"))
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `bool` there

Comment: No need to convert to `bool`

Comment: There's no need to call the `bool` constructor.  Also, you can say `x in ("val1", "val2")`.

Answer (score 1):

why not just:

```
inp = x in ("val1", "val2")
```

of cause it can be compacted even more directly in the call to the next function, but that will be at the cost of some readability, imho.

Answer (score 0):

You usually put the test in a function and spell out the consequence:

```
def test(x):
    # aka `return x in ("val1", "val2")` but thats another story
    if x=="val1" or x == "val2" :
      res = True
    else
      res = False    
    return res

def dostuff(inp):
    # i guess this function is supposed to do something with inp
    x = a_function_assigns_values_of_x(inp)
    if test(x):
      do_something
    else :
      dont_do_something

dostuff(inp)
```